# Calling a function without parameters, but its defined to have parameters?

Tags: c, stm32

**I'm looking at this example:** https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STMems_Standard_C_drivers/tree/master/lsm9ds1_STdC

**I'm trying to understand how in the code below *platform_write_imu* is called without any parameters?**

```
    static int32_t platform_write_imu(void *handle, uint8_t reg, uint8_t *bufp,
                                     uint16_t len);
    static int32_t platform_read_imu(void *handle, uint8_t reg, uint8_t *bufp,
                                    uint16_t len);
    static int32_t platform_write_mag(void *handle, uint8_t reg, uint8_t *bufp,
                                     uint16_t len);
    static int32_t platform_read_mag(void *handle, uint8_t reg, uint8_t *bufp,
                                    uint16_t len);
    
    /* Main Example --------------------------------------------------------------*/
    void lsm9ds1_read_data_polling(void)
    {
     stmdev_ctx_t dev_ctx_imu;
    
     /* Initialize inertial sensors (IMU) driver interface */
     dev_ctx_imu.write_reg = platform_write_imu;
     dev_ctx_imu.read_reg = platform_read_imu;
     dev_ctx_imu.handle = (void*)&imu_bus;
```

**What is the role of the function pointer *void handle* when it is not defined anywhere? This code builds BTW**

```
    static int32_t platform_write_imu(void *handle, uint8_t reg, uint8_t *bufp,
                                     uint16_t len)
    {
     sensbus_t *sensbus = (sensbus_t*)handle;
     
     #if defined(NUCLEO_F411RE)
     HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(sensbus->hbus, sensbus->i2c_address, reg,
                       I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, bufp, len, 1000);
     #endif
     return 0;
    }
```

Just would like to know what is happening here in terms of sequence.

Comment: `dev_ctx_imu.write_reg = platform_write_imu;` is this the statement you are asking about? if yes, then its not the call, its just storing/assigning the address of function there, then when required it would be called as `dev_ctx_imu.write_reg(handle, reg, bufp,t len)`

Comment: And where is the call? `dev_ctx_imu.write_reg = platform_write_imu;` is assignment, assigning the function pointer to a variable, it's not a function call.

Comment: `void *handle` is not a function pointer. It is a pointer to void data.

Comment: `dev_ctx_imu.write_reg = platform_write_imu;` is not a call but the assignment of a function (pointer) to the left hand side.

Answer (score 1):

```
dev_ctx_imu.write_reg = platform_write_imu;
/* ... */
```

It assigns the function pointers with the address of the function. It is not the call.

> What is the role of the function pointer void handle when it is not
> defined anywhere?

It is not function pointer only a pointer to void data.

> Just would like to know what is happening here in terms of sequence.

It is just a normal parameter. Does not have any sequence.

BTW to program uCs you need to learn C much better. My advise - learn using your PC, when you understand pointers, arrays & function pointers well come back to the embedded.